# Is there any better way of checking a variable is array and is not empty?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I want to know in php is there any better way of knowing a variable is array and is not empty.
I've been using this

```
 if (!empty($collection) && is_array($collection)) {

}
```

Comment: Nope doesn't get less verbose than this. I guess you could make this into a function if you had to call it a lot. You could wrap this in a for-loop too if you're checking multiple variables.

Comment: use sizeof function to check array is empty or not if return 0 then array is empty(alternative option).

Comment: `if (is_array($collection) && count($collection) > 0 ) {`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this condition for checking array:

```
if (isset($collection) && count($collection) >0 && is_array($collection)) {
        //you code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to 'know'. You can var_dump($collection) that.